# I get `this.getOptions is not a function` error when using coffee-loader on Rails 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, coffeescript, webpacker

I created a brand new Rails app with Ruby 2.7.2 and Ruby on Rails 6.1.3:

```sh
rails new rails6
```

Then I installed the CoffeeScript compiler using the Rails command:

```sh
rails webpacker:install:coffee
```

But when i started the webpack-dev-server, he was unable to compile correctly:

```sh
                                      Asset       Size        Chunks                         Chunk Names
     js/application-30c16ea0138c526e20f5.js    515 KiB   application  [emitted] [immutable]  application
 js/application-30c16ea0138c526e20f5.js.map    579 KiB   application  [emitted] [dev]        application
    js/hello_coffee-5eba0c58c2666f949e88.js    395 KiB  hello_coffee  [emitted] [immutable]  hello_coffee
js/hello_coffee-5eba0c58c2666f949e88.js.map    444 KiB  hello_coffee  [emitted] [dev]        hello_coffee
                              manifest.json  710 bytes                [emitted]

ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/hello_coffee.coffee
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/coffee-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at Object.loader (/Users/iwan/dev/rails/rails6/node_modules/coffee-loader/dist/index.js:21:24)
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 9):

I found that downgrading coffee-loader to the version 1.0.1 removed the error.

Edit package.json and change the version from

```sh
"coffee-loader": "^2.0.0",
```

to

```sh
"coffee-loader": "1.0.1",
```

Then run `yarn install --check-files` to apply the change.

Happy days!

Comment: Thanks Iwan! This worked for me! Ruby 2.7.2, Rails 6.1.2(.1)